# Get the current location from telegram using API

Tags: api, gps, telegram

I have a telegram bot where I use custom buttons to interact with the users. I need now to get from then the current location using the GPS information. It is possible, using the telegram API to get the latitude and longitude from devices?

This is my PHP code:

```
  if($text == '/start')
  {
    $botid = $xtokenid;
    $chatid = $chat_id;
    $reply = "Bem vindo ao EYB18, canal de informações online!";
    $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot$botid/sendMessage";

    $keyboard = array('keyboard' => array(array("Localização")),'resize_keyboard' => true,'one_time_keyboard' => false,'request_location' => true);

    $postfields = array('chat_id' => "$chatid",'text' => "$reply",'reply_markup' => json_encode($keyboard));

    $str = str_replace('\\\\', '\\', $postfields);

    print_r($str);
    if (!$curld = curl_init()) {
    exit;
    }

    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $str);
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $output = curl_exec($curld);

    curl_close ($curld);
  }
```

Tks.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending a keyboard which will ask users to send their location. If they press this button or even if they send any location from the map, your bot will get message object containing location object. Location object contains longitude and latitude.

Here is the full list of message object properties: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message

Here is location object: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#location